# Separation of variables for nonhomogeneous PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need to solve the equation below using separation of variables.
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = 2$$
 The thing is, i've always done with $0$ after the equal sign. I'm really stuck with that $2$; when doing the separation I get $X'Y-XY'=2$ and can't separate X and Y after that.

Comment: Did try to substitute $f=h(x,y)-2y$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = 2$$
Substitute $f(x,y)=h(x,y)+2x$
$$\frac{\partial h(x,y)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial h(x,y)}{\partial y} =0 $$

Comment: This. Now I'm able to solve the problem. Many thanks, my friend!

Comment: @Alexandre yes you can solve it now you're welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a,b)$ be some vector such that $a-b=2$. Then,

$$f_x-f_y=2=(1,-1) \cdot (a,b)$$

$$(1,-1) \cdot (f_x,f_y)=(1,-1) \cdot (a,b)$$

It follows that $(f_x-a,f_y-b)$ is orthogonal to $(1,-1)$. Let $g(x,y)=f(x,y)-ax-by$. Then $\nabla g$ is orthogonal to $(1,-1)$. So $\nabla g=\lambda(1,1)$ and $g(x,y)=\lambda (x+y)$. Hence $\lambda(x+y)+ax+by=f(x,y)$. Or with $b=2-a$:

$$f(x,y)=\lambda(x+y)+ax+(2-a)x$$

$$=\lambda x+ \lambda y+2 x$$