# Partial Differential Equations : Separation of Variables in Second Order Linear Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I know how to solve this homogeneous problem using separation of variables .
Here, $u$ is from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 0$$

But,  How to solve this non homogeneous equation using separation of variables 
$$ u_ {xx} + u_{yy} = 1 $$
There are no boundary conditions given in question.

I am new in solving PDE,  so please explain the answer as well.

Comment: Can you make a change of variables that gets rid of the $1$? Maybe something like $v(x,t) = u(x,t) + x^{2}/2$, though you could equally take $v(x,t) = u(x,t) + y^{2}/2$. It usually depends on what the boundary conditions are.

Comment: Why you have used $(x, t)$ ?  $u$ is a function of $(x, y) $

Comment: It was a typo. Just replace $t$ with $y$ in what I wrote in the previous comment.

Comment: There was literally a problem just like this one posted a couple of days ago. Duplicate?

Comment: @DaveNine,  Can you please share link of that. So, that I can know if there is one more method to solve it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3000327/17243 it’s literally on the same page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separation of variables for nonhomogeneous PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000327/separation-of-variables-for-nonhomogeneous-pde)

Comment: Thanks : I got that although that was first order equation.